# Is there a similar equivalence like the divergence theorem for surface integrals non-linear in the normal vector?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-forms

The divergence theorem can be stated as

$$\bigcirc \hspace{-1.3em} \int \hspace{-.8em} \int\limits_{\partial\Omega} dA\,n_i = \iiint\limits_\Omega dV\partial_i$$

applied to an arbitrary function (usually a vector valued field) where $\partial\Omega$ is the closed surface of the volume $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and $n_i$ is the $i$th component of the surface normal vector $\vec n$.

Is there a similar correspondence between e.g.

$$\bigcirc \hspace{-1.3em} \int \hspace{-.8em} \int\limits_{\partial\Omega} dA\,n_i n_j$$

and another volume integral?

Comment: @Matt thanks, I tried `\oiint` but didn't think `\oint` would work instead...

Comment: That's ok, I was just curious and the result turned out ok. Somebody probably knows how to center the limit properly as well.

Comment: @MattPressland I found a nice `\oiint` [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/17706782/115/A-new-oiint-command)

Comment: That looks better! (I didn't actually realise the circle was supposed to go through both integrals).